# How to passing parameter to afterSave() Method in yii2?

Tags: yii2, after-save

I'm new to **yii2**. I want to write `afterSave()` method after insert new record. My scenario is: when the user add a damage must be send email to him.
When user add damage, does not enter the serial number.  I should read his name and serial damage but I don't know how to passing serial from Controller to model.

**Damage Model**:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

 public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    $name = $this->user->name;
    $serial = ?
    $to = $this->user->email;
    $subject = 'new damage';
    $body = 'mr'.$name.'your damage with serial number'.$serial.'is registered';
    if ($insert) {

        App::sendMail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
}
```

**DamageController**:

```
public function actionAddDamage($serial){

  $model = new Damage();
  $gaurantee = Gaurantee::find()->where(['serial' =>  $serial])->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
  if (!$gaurantee)
        throw  new ForbiddenHttpException('You don't access');
  $model->gr_id = $gaurantee->id;
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
  return $this->render('addDamage',
            ['model' => $model,
                'servers' => $servers,
                'gaurantee' => $gaurantee,
            ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that comes to mind is to add attribute in damage model.

```
//Damage model
public $serial;
```

Then in your controller you can set value for this:

```
public function actionAddDamage($serial){
      $model = new Damage();
      $gaurantee = Gaurantee::find()->where(['serial' =>       $serial])->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
      if (!$gaurantee)
          throw  new ForbiddenHttpException("you don't access");
      $model->serial = $serial;
      .....
```

In your `afterSave()` method you will have your serial as `$this->serial`.

2nd way is to get it from guaranty table since you have `$this->gr_id` , but this will generate 1 more db request.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function init(){
        $this->on(self::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT, [$this, 'sendMail']);               
    }

public function sendMail($event) {

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property `$serial` in your Damage Model and assign the serial value to the `$model->serial` property in your Controller. For Example:

```
class Damage extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $serial = null;

    public function afterSave($insert, $changeAttributes) {
         // ...
         var_dump($this->serial);
    }
}
```

And in the controller you can assign $serial to the model:

```
public function actionAddDamage($serial) {

    $model = new Damage();
    $model->serial = $serial;

    // ...

}
```